# Validate Radio buttons in a popup

Tags: javascript, popup, radio-button

I'm struggling to find a solution. I hope you can help?

I have created a popup with radio buttons which I need users to select. I have managed to put this into a popup but now I am trying to show an error message if someone tries to click 'Submit' before selecting an option.

The code I have so far is not working as I would like. My Submit button continues to fade out the popup even if no selection has been made.

JS

```
    $("#myModal").draggable({
      handle: ".modal-header"
  });

$("#loadpage").click(function (e)
    {
        HideDialog();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
function setCookie(name, value, days) { // from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
window.onload = function () {
    var myVar = getCookie('Cookie Consent');
    console.log(myVar)
    if (myVar) {
        if (myVar=="Level 1") document.getElementById('Level 1').click(); // or .checked=true; 
        else if (myVar=="Level 2") document.getElementById('Level 2').click();
    }
    document.getElementById('loadpage').onclick = function () {
        var m = document.getElementById('Level 1');
        var f = document.getElementById('Level 2');
        var t = document.getElementById('Level 3');
        if (m.checked) {
            setCookie('cookie consent', m.value, 365);
        } else if (f.checked) {
            setCookie('cookie consent', f.value, 365);
        } else if (t.checked) {
            setCookie('cookie consent', t.value, 365);
        }
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
    });
 });


//Controls how the modal popup is closed with the close button
function HideDialog()
{
    $("#myModal").fadeOut(300);
    }

$(function()
  {
    $('#myform').validate(
      {
        rules:
        {
          toggler:{ required:true }
        },
        messages:
        {
          toggler:
          {
            required:"Please select an option<br/>"
          }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
        {
            if ( element.is(":radio") ) 
            {
               error.appendTo( element.parents('#myform') );
            }
            else 
            { // This is the default behavior 
                error.insertAfter( element );
            }
         }
      });

  });
```

Here's my [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/TomScogg/pen/KorYeO)

Hope you can help? Thank you.

Cheers

Comment: im getting this error in code pen `$(...).validate is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
  option1<input type="radio" name="foo" value="option1" required>
  option2<input type="radio" name="foo" value="option2">
  option3<input type="radio" name="foo" value="option3">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Just add required to one of the radio buttons. Then the browser already has validation for the form and will give an error if no radio button is selected.

In addition you could also use checked on the option which is most often selected, this way the user has by default always selected something. You can use checked like this:

```
<input type="radio" checked>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work within my popup modal. The submit button fades the modal even without a selection being made.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the DOMlist of input type radio using selectors and then use [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate each one of them and then you can add custom validation or CSS as per your requirements. Example

```
  $("#loadpage").click(function (e)
{
  $("input[name='toggler']").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    alert("checked")
}
})
    HideDialog();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Updated Codepen link [here](https://codepen.io/TomScogg/pen/KorYeO?editors=1010)

Comment: Please check the code above it will solve your problem